# How to call Java methods from my jar file inside the Python Scripts

Tags: java, python

I am writing the python module where I need to interact with java module for some work.
I have already jar for java layer. 
I can I invoke the jar files and call the class/Methods which are there in Jar files.

I don't want to use the Jython since major of my code is pure python

I tried `subprocess.call()`
but it's not serving my purpose

```
subprocess.call(['java','-jar', 'my.jar'])
```

EDIT:
I need to call the java layer because I need some input to my python module from there.

I tried py4j but no successes

Comment: Why is it not serving your purpose? Please add more details about your problem, what you have tried, and why it didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to do something based on the output your java program provides?

Answer (score 1):

[JPype](https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is an alternative to Jython that I made some good experience with. If it is not enough to call the java program and work with the output (it's hard to tell from your question), then JPype can be used to (more or less) transparently work with Java object in Python code.

I works by starting a JVM and handing requests to said JVM.

Comment: I will try and let you know